# Early language acquisition from non-native input

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition

[This answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/how-to-teach-a-child-a-foreign-language-at-home-when-both-parents-arent-native/10611#10611) on the Parenting Stack Exchange describes the possible effect on a child's overall language ability when well-meaning immigrant parents with limited mastery of the local language attempt to raise their children in that language rather than in their own.

I would like some references to research on this issue, particularly quantitative measures of the degree of long-term language impairment.

Also, is there a threshold level of L2 ability in the parents above which any negative effects are minimal (for instance, if they become undetectable once exposure to the local language begins at school)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about the process of the language acquisition, hence off topic here. It can fit better at [languagelearning.se].

Comment: @bytebuster The [help page](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) refers to a number of on-topic "subcategories" that can be found [here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/faq-linguistics-disciplines-and-sub-disciplines). One of these subcategories is "language acquisition." Note that I am not asking for "advice or help on learning a foreign language."

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me. Linguistics programs include courses on theory of acquisition! As for a sketch of an answer, two points: (1) The children of immigrants almost invariably speak the local language better than their parents ever learn to, and I'm sure we all know of many such cases. Out-of-home exposure is simply that powerful. After all, as Chomsky pointed out long ago, children need startlingly little data to generate fluency. (2) Consider that Hebrew was revived by L2 speakers raising L1 speakers when none of the latter existed. Now there are 9 million L1 speakers...

Comment: I like the answers in that thread, which tend towards the suggestion that parents bring in other people or resources that can serve as authorities. Children will generally sort it out from there. (Of course, a complete answer would include some of the data you asked for, hence this as a comment.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak My question is about the effect on children when they have little or no exposure to *any* language spoken competently before they are of school age. The gist of the answer on the parenting site is that if I move to Norway and try to speak bad Norwegian to my child until he eventually goes to school, and that is the only input he's getting for many years, then he'll be far worse off in the long run than if I speak to him in English now and he learns Norwegian later from Norwegians. My question is asking for references to hard research on this issue.

Comment: With respect to Hebrew, it doesn't seem out of the question that some of the people who only heard poor L2 Hebrew could have been affected negatively by this experience, and that it took a generation for spoken Israeli Hebrew to gain the regularity of a natural language. However, there would also have been a number of extremely competent L2 Hebrew speakers. I imagine that the very first L1 speakers would have been raised by people of this kind.

Comment: The regularity of a natural language? Surely you mean the *ir*regularity. ;) And fair enough re: parents who avoid speaking the L2. In that case the Hebrew example becomes all the more interesting. But yes, without hard research to point you to, I should probably stop speculating!

Comment: I mean regularity. Nonfluency in an L2 is often characterized by inconsistent application of rules. For example, if you speak French you might say "une école" one time and "un école" the next. Perhaps "irregularity" isn't the word for this, but I've heard many L2 speakers of English use nothing but the present tense. What does it do to a child to hear only the present tense for the first five years of his life (without any of the compensating structures that might be present in languages with a different tense system)?